# Count with condition in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called `shop order`. It contains different part numbers like:

```
part_no
-------
1252
1222
2222
2589
3564
4587
.
.
.
9565
9623
```

The question now is how can I count and show part_no, grouping by the first digit?

For example, I want to show count part_no `like '1%' = 3` (result: count1 =3) and count part_no `like '2%' = 2` (result: count2 = 2)..... Count9 =2.

Result:

```
1st digit   count
---------   -----
1           3
2           2
9           2
```

Is it possible to show the result from count 1 to count 9 in one go?

Answer (score 3):

That would be

```
select substr(part, 1, 1) as grp,
       count(*) as cnt
from shop_order
group by substr(part, 1, 1);
```

---

For example (based on Scott's EMP table):

```
SQL> select empno, ename, substr(empno, 2) as part from emp order by 3;

     EMPNO ENAME      PART
---------- ---------- -----
      7369 SMITH      369     3 - count = 1
      7499 ALLEN      499     4 - count = 1
      7521 WARD       521     5 - count = 2
      7566 JONES      566
      7654 MARTIN     654     6 - count = 2
      7698 BLAKE      698
      7782 CLARK      782     7 - count = 2
      7788 SCOTT      788
      7839 KING       839     8 - count = 3
      7844 TURNER     844
      7876 ADAMS      876
      7900 JAMES      900     9 - count = 3
      7902 FORD       902
      7934 MILLER     934

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Then you'd have

```
SQL> with shop_order (part) as
  2    (select substr(empno, 2) from emp)
  3  select substr(part, 1, 1) as grp,
  4         count(*) cnt
  5  from shop_order
  6  group by substr(part, 1, 1)
  7  order by substr(part, 1, 1);

GRP         CNT
---- ----------
3             1
4             1
5             2
6             2
7             2
8             3
9             3

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation, if you want the counts in separate columns:

```
select sum(case when part like '1%' then 1 else 0 end) as count_1,
       sum(case when part like '2%' then 1 else 0 end) as count_2,
       . . .
       sum(case when part like '9%' then 1 else 0 end) as count_9
from shop_order so;
```